# VBA: Unexpected Behavior In IF-statement.

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am using VBA for Microsoft Excel 2007. My code is as follows:

```
 Sub First()

 End Sub

 Function Two() As Boolean

 End Function

 Sub Sun()
     If (Two()) Then
         First()
     End If
 End Sub
```

What is wrong with this code? Why does it not compile?

Can I not use subs in `IF` statements? Is it a [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_%28programming%29) of VBA? How can or should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis from the call to `First`.

```
Sub First()

End Sub

Function Two() As Boolean

End Function

Sub Sun()
    If (Two()) Then
        First
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! and if `First(arg as Variant)` i must write `First arg`, yes?

Comment: @loldop -- I think so. VBA has some strange argument requirements. If the sub/function returns a value, and that value is placed in a variable, then parenthesis are required. If no value is returned, then you have to omit the parenthesis.

Comment: Here's a nice write up of parentheses by Rick Rothstein.  http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/#comment-79416

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```
Sub First()

End Sub

Function Two() As Boolean

End Function

Sub Sun()
    If (Two()) Then
        First
    End If
End Sub
```

You need to remove the parentheses from your `First` call.